# "Variable does not exist: Name" exception when trying to call from a sObject

Tags: soql, sobject

```
public class test {
    public sObject s = [Select name from Merchandise__c where name='pencils'];
}
```

The code is compiled successfully but when i try to execute the code from the anonymous window by using the following code:

```
system.debug(new test().s.Name);
```

i get the following error message:

```
Line: 1, Column: 27
Variable does not exist: Name
```

If instead of of the above i write the following in anonymous window:

```
system.debug(new test().s.id);
```

OR

```
system.debug(new test().s);
```

It runs succesfully
Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the generic sObject doesn't return any other field except Id using dot notation.

So if you want to get the field from sObject you need to do

```
s.get('Name'); //pass field API here
```

or better you can create a sObject instance and simply use the Dot Notation.

```
public Merchandise__c s = [Select name from Merchandise__c where name='pencils' LIMIT 1];
system.debug(new test().s.Name);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because sObject is a generic type: it has an Id, but not a name. Please change sObject in your code to Merchandise__c. That is also better practise.